# Extension function collision

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

When I define two extension functions with the same signature I get an `conflicting overloads` error, even if the extension functions are defined in different files.

Does this make different libraries that define the same extension function incompatible to each other?
Say, both libraries declare extension functions on `String` with the same name and parameters. Is there still any way to use these two libraries in the same project?

Comment: Thank you. Neither Google nor Stackoverflow turned this up.

Comment: Yes, they will clash, and that's why it is always a good idea, especially if you are writing a library, to use packages, so that there's a way to keep them apart (then the user can choose from which package to import).